# Android Studio remove HTML input from a string and get the value

Tags: java, html, regex, string, android-studio

I am reading in a input html string from a buffer. Now I need to get the value from the string. Here is my string:

```
rowBuffer = <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="01234abcABC">
```

I have tested this in curl with:

```
 grep -oP '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="\K([0-9a-zA-Z]+)'
```

but not sure how to do this in the Android Studio

Comment: row Buffer is <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="0123abcABC">
grep -oP '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="\K([0-9a-zA-Z]+)'

Answer (score 0):

> but not sure how to do this in the Android Studio

In Java (tested):

```
    String rowBuffer = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_token\" value=\"01234abcABC\">";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<input[^>]+value=\"(.*?)\">").matcher(rowBuffer);
    m.matches();
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(m.group(1), Matchers.equalTo("01234abcABC"));
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ncD1Wm/1) of the regex pattern.

Comment: I tried that but it gives No successful match so far.

Comment: I changed my comment to a tested version.

Comment: Works great. I didn't need the MatcherAssert line. The value changes overtime and has 40 characters. Just was showing it had numbers and upper and lower characters. Thank you